# Downcale a video with NReco VideoConverter

Tags: c#, .net, video, mp4

Im using the NReco VideoConverter DLL from this source http://www.nrecosite.com/
Im trying to convert a 720p video down to a 360p H264 formatted mp4 file.
A file is produced but WMP cannot play it.

Here is my code

```
    var setting = new NReco.VideoConverter.ConvertSettings();

    setting.SetVideoFrameSize(360, 360);
    setting.VideoCodec = "h264";

    var converter = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();

    converter.ConvertMedia("infile.mp4", "mp4", "output.mp4", "mp4", setting);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using `setting.VideoCodec = "mpeg4";`